# Primefaces Calendar setDate not working properly

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm facing an issue when trying to set the date and time of Calendar in **primefaces 6.1** using javascript. I used the following code and at first, it was working but suddenly it stopped working. Now I can't figure out how to fix this thing. Sometimes it changes the date part but not the time part.

```
var recievedDateValue = PF('recievedDate').getDate();
PF('collectedDate').setDate(recievedDateValue);
```

XHTML Part:

```
<p:calendar id="caseCollectedDate" widgetVar="collectedDate" tabindex="50" value="#{caseController.selectedCase.caseCollectedDate}"
                            converter="DateConverter"
                            converterMessage="Please enter valid date time format" pattern="MM/dd/yy HH:mm" maxdate="#{viewUtilityBean.currentDate}"
                            timeControlType="slider" onfocus="getFocusElementId()" onchange="validateDate('collectedDate')">
                    <p:remoteCommand name="validateCollectedDateFromServer" update="@this"/>
</p:calendar>
```

DateConverter (getAsObject method):

```
if (!value.contains(":")) {
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse(value);
            value = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm").format(date1.getTime());
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm").parse(value);
} else {
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm").parse(value);
}
```

I tried multiple ways to somehow work this but it is not working. Though setdate function calls the **onchange** event but the date doesn't change. 
I overrode the setDate function of the **primefaces** calendar widget to the following.

The following are the snippets I tried.

```
setDate : function(a) {
    var month = a.getMonth();
    var date = a.getDate();
    var year = a.getFullYear();

    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    this.jqEl.datetimepicker("setDate",new Date(month,date,year,hour,min))
}


setDate : function(a) {
    var month = a.getMonth();
    var date = a.getDate();
    var year = a.getFullYear();

    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    this.jqEl.datetimepicker({
        userCurrent: false,
        format: 'MM-dd-yy HH:mm',
        date: new Date(month,date,year,hour,min)
    })
}

setDate : function(a) {
    var month = a.getMonth();
    var date = a.getDate();
    var year = a.getFullYear();

    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    this.jqEl.datetimepicker({
        date: new Date(month,date,year,hour,min)
    })
}

setDate : function(a) {
    var month = a.getMonth();
    var date = a.getDate();
    var year = a.getFullYear();

    var onlyDate = month+"/"+date+"/"+year;

    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    this.jqEl.datetimepicker({
        date: onlyDate,
        hour: hour,
        minute: min
    })
}

setDate : function(a) {
    $('#clientTabs\\:j_idt1125\\:caseCollectedDate_input').data("DateTimePicker").date(a);
}
```

Calendar looks[image] like this.

Comment: What happens when you call `widget.getDate()` take that value and turn around and put it in `setDate()`?  Update your description above to include the PrimeFaces version please.

Comment: @Melloware question updated about PrimeFaces Version and Also about getDate() method. I do take a value as getDate() and then set it in setDate() function

Comment: What about using the calendar attribute dateConverter? try that thing out so it can convert any date it receives

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast please look into the updated question.

Comment: Is three any way you can test if this is fixed in 6.2 or 7.0.  There have been tons of bugs fixed since 6.1 and its very possible this was already fixed.